# Change the graphical representation of a sparse correlation matrix

Tags: r, plot

I have this sparse squared matrix which contains squared correlation.

```
tmp <- readRDS(url("https://www.dropbox.com/s/65u96jf7y32j2mj/spMat.rds?raw=1"))
Matrix::image(tmp)
```

[image]

This matrix is super sparse and have non-zero values located only around the diagonal. I would like to make another representation, which would look like this (forget the axes):

[image]

So, basically, I want to view only the upper triangle, rotated by 45° and with a limited  height.

Anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not exatly the same plot but fairly similar:

```
## Transform sparse representation into (i,j,x) triplets
tmpT <- as(tmp, "dgTMatrix")

## get the "coordinates" of the non-0 elements in the upper triangle and rotate them by 45°
upper <- tmpT@i < tmpT@j
coords <- cbind(tmpT@i[upper], tmpT@j[upper])
coords <- t(matrix(c(sqrt(2), -sqrt(2), sqrt(2), sqrt(2))/2, ncol = 2) %*% t(coords))

## plot the rotated coordinates and take the transparency from the value
plot(coords, cex=.4, pch=18, col=rgb(0, 0, 0, tmpT@x[upper]), ylim = c(0, 50), asp=2)
```

[image]

Comment: Seems good. Sorry, I won't be able to check this before Monday.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It inspires me for my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @AEF's answer, I made this:

```
library(tidyverse)
## Transform sparse representation into (i,j,x) triplets
tmpT <- as(tmp, "dgTMatrix")
upper <- (tmpT@i <= tmpT@j)
df <- data.frame(
  i = tmpT@i[upper], 
  j = tmpT@j[upper],
  r2 = tmpT@x[upper]
) %>%
  mutate(y = (j - i) / 2)

ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(i + y, y, color = r2, alpha = r2), size = rel(0.5)) +
  coord_fixed() + 
  scale_color_gradientn(colours = rev(colorRamps::matlab.like2(100))) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.ticks.y = element_blank()) +
  labs(x = "Position", y = NULL) + 
  scale_alpha(guide = 'none')
```

[image]

PS: `RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(9, "Greys")[-(1:2)]` is great if you want a grey scale.